# Why does capistrano abort during deploy?

Tags: ruby, node.js, capistrano

My first day with Capistrano, and I'm a total Ruby noob. When I run `cap production deploy` I get: (about half-way down you'll see "cap aborted!")

```
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
 INFO Uploading /tmp/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [a4358a68] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/git-ssh.sh on 205.149.129.67
DEBUG [a4358a68] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/git-ssh.sh
 INFO [a4358a68] Finished in 0.094 seconds command successful.
 INFO [7e2d6b30] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:johnnyfreeman/ng-phrases-node.git on 205.149.129.67
DEBUG [7e2d6b30] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:johnnyfreeman/ng-phrases-node.git )
DEBUG [7e2d6b30]    870ca21b256ec53ffba50da1d8ecf7cb4c36e561
DEBUG [7e2d6b30]        
DEBUG [7e2d6b30]    HEAD
DEBUG [7e2d6b30]    
DEBUG [7e2d6b30]    870ca21b256ec53ffba50da1d8ecf7cb4c36e561
DEBUG [7e2d6b30]        
DEBUG [7e2d6b30]    refs/heads/master
DEBUG [7e2d6b30]    
 INFO [7e2d6b30] Finished in 2.289 seconds command successful.
 INFO [982c4c8c] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/shared /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/releases on 205.149.129.67
DEBUG [982c4c8c] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/shared /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/releases
 INFO [982c4c8c] Finished in 1.084 seconds command successful.
DEBUG [b52bf507] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo/HEAD ] on 205.149.129.67
DEBUG [b52bf507] Command: [ -f /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG [b52bf507] Finished in 1.151 seconds command successful.
 INFO The repository mirror is at /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo
DEBUG [5a6d473a] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on 205.149.129.67
DEBUG [5a6d473a] Command: if test ! -d /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [5a6d473a] Finished in 1.022 seconds command successful.
 INFO [ebde0a3b] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update on 205.149.129.67
DEBUG [ebde0a3b] Command: cd /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo && /usr/bin/env git remote update
DEBUG [ebde0a3b]    Fetching origin
DEBUG [ebde0a3b]    
 INFO [ebde0a3b] Finished in 1.485 seconds command successful.
DEBUG [42faf760] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on 205.149.129.67
DEBUG [42faf760] Command: if test ! -d /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [42faf760] Finished in 1.195 seconds command successful.
 INFO [7c34b6a2] Running /usr/bin/env git clone --branch master --depth 1 --recursive --no-hardlinks /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/releases/20130807190743 on 205.149.129.67
DEBUG [7c34b6a2] Command: cd /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git clone --branch master --depth 1 --recursive --no-hardlinks /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/repo /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/releases/20130807190743 )
DEBUG [7c34b6a2]    warning: --depth is ignored in local clones; use file:// instead.
DEBUG [7c34b6a2]    
DEBUG [7c34b6a2]    Cloning into '/home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/releases/20130807190743'...
DEBUG [7c34b6a2]    
DEBUG [7c34b6a2]    done.
DEBUG [7c34b6a2]    
 INFO [7c34b6a2] Finished in 0.259 seconds command successful.
 INFO [e945e1c7] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/current on 205.149.129.67
DEBUG [e945e1c7] Command: /usr/bin/env rm -rf /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/current
 INFO [e945e1c7] Finished in 1.062 seconds command successful.
 INFO [51d6629e] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/releases/20130807190743 /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/current on 205.149.129.67
DEBUG [51d6629e] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/releases/20130807190743 /home/deploy/ng-phrases-node/current
 INFO [51d6629e] Finished in 0.074 seconds command successful.
cap aborted!
Your filter `(no filter)` would remove all matching servers
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/configuration/servers.rb:73:in `filtered_servers'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/configuration/servers.rb:53:in `filter'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/configuration/servers.rb:48:in `fetch_roles'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/configuration/servers.rb:17:in `roles_for'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/configuration.rb:41:in `roles_for'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/dsl/env.rb:39:in `roles'
/home/johnny/Projects/ng-phrases-node/Capfile:30:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:14:in `invoke'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:14:in `invoke'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:66:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:65:in `each'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/tasks/framework.rake:65:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0.pre14/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/johnny/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:restart
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm really not sure what the problem is here and I don't see anything in the docs about Capistrano and filters.

Not sure what other information would be relevant to know here, so if I've left anything out please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano 3's deploy task depends on a task named deploy:restart. Unlike the other tasks in the default deploy flow, the behaviour of deploy:restart isn't predefined for you; you need to customize it depending on the applications server you use. When you run `cap install` a skeleton task is created for you to edit in your Capfile that looks like this.

```
desc 'Restart application'
task :restart do
  on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
    # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
    # execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
  end
end
```

`on roles(:app)` tells capistrano to execute this method on the servers you gave the app role in *config/deploy/production.rb*. I think you didn't assign any servers this role, so capistrano is complaining it doesn't have anywhere to run this task. Now, you could modify this task to run on another role. However, the predefined tasks related to linked files and directories also refer to the app role, so if you started using them (e.g. for database.yml) capistrano would throw this error again. Thus, I think the better choice is to give your server the app role.